# Rule to create triangular matrices

Tags: matrix, replacement, rule

```
Triang[n_][a_] := 
 Table[a[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}] /. {(a_[n_, k_] /; k > n) -> 0}
```

I would like to write a rule which replaces all the entries in the upper triangle of a matrix with 0.
The above code does not work (I know that in advance). Is there a way to modify the substitution rule in a way this works?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, please check the documentation [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html). Can you explain a little bit what you want to do in the code(even though it is wrong)? what the expressions mean? so that we can help.

Comment: Aside from that, it is considered bad practice to use capital letters for the first letter of a user created function.

Comment: Why not use `SparseArray[]` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this was a silly question, just a naming collision.
This works:

```
Triang[n_][a_] := 
 Table[a[i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}] /. {(m_[x_, y_] /; y > x) -> 0}
```

Comment: Can you tell how this works?